# Delete All Records using Liferay Service Builder

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I can delete specific record using Liferay Service Builder but what to do when I want to delete All the Records from that table.

I am new to Liferay So any Help would be appreciated...!!!

Comment: There would be `removeAll()` method in your `XXXPersistence`, you can call this method in your `XXXServiceImpl` to remove all record for that entity.

Comment: @ParkashKumar : will u please elaborate by giving code snippet ?

Comment: What is your entity name? Are your able to find `XXXUtil.java` in your generated service?

Comment: Yes I am able to find LocationLocalServiceUtil class & I am also able to delete specific record using locationId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your entity name is `Location`, add following method in your `LocationLocalServiceImpl.java` and build service:

```
public void deleteAllLocations(){
    try{
        LocationUtil.removeAll();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        // Log exception here.
    }
}
```

On successful build, `deleteAllLocations` will be copied to `LocationLocalServiceUtil.java` from where you can use it in your action class as:

```
LocationLocalServiceUtil.deleteAllLocations();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question already has an answer that the asker is satisfied with but I thought I'd add another just the same. Since you're writing custom method in your service implementation (in your case `LocationLocalServiceImpl`):

1. You have direct access to the persistence bean so there is no need to use the `LocationUtil`.
2. The accepted answer suggests catching any `Exception` and logging it. I disagree with this because it will fail silently and depending on the application logic, could cause problems later on. For example, if your `removeAll` is called within a transaction whose success depends on the correct removal of all entities and the accepted approach fails, the transaction won't be rolled back since you don't throw a `SystemException`.

With this in mind, consider the following (within your implementation, as above):

```
public void deleteAllLocations() throws SystemException {
    locationPersistence.removeAll();
}
```

Then, wherever you're calling it from (for example in a controller), you have control over what happens in the case of a failure

```
try {
    LocationLocalServiceUtil.removeAllLocations();
} catch (SystemException e) {
    // here whatever you've removed has been rolled back
    // instead of just logging it, warn the user that an error occurred
    SessionErrors.add(portletRequest, "your-error-key");
    log.error("An error occurred while removing all locations", e);
}
```

Having said that, your `LocationUtil` class is available outside of the service so you can call it from a controller. If your goal is only to remove all `Location` entities without doing anything else within the context of that transaction, you can just use the `LocationUtil` in your controller. This would save you from having to rebuild the service layer.